# How do I turn categorical column values into different column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I'm not sure how to approach this problem since I'm a beginner with pandas.

I have this dataframe:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    1 
1    a    2 
2    a    3 
3    b    4
4    b    5
5    b    6
6    c    7
7    c    8
8    c    9
```

and I want to turn it into a dataframe or a matrix like this:

```
   cola colb  colc
0    1    4    7
1    2    5    8
2    3    6    9
```

How should I approach this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `groupby` the dataframe on `col1` and create key-value pairs inside `dict` comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: [*g['col2']] for k, g in df.groupby('col1')})
```

Alternatively, you can use `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a sequential counter to distinguish different rows per group in `col1`, then use `set_index` + `unstack` to reshape:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('col1').cumcount(), 'col1'])['col2'].unstack()
```

Another approach with `pivot_table` with `groupby` + `cumcount`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('col1').cumcount(), columns='col1', values='col2')
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: As a side note: In order to use the first approach you must have the same number of rows per group  in `col1`, but for the second and third approach its not required..